# What to do when user doesn't check his own question?

Tags: discussion

Some time ago I answered a few question where user haven't log in for such a long time (the only session was connected with the creation of the question).

Do you often meet with a similar situation?

[Prestashop 1.6 SSL error on Mobiles/Tablets using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167653/prestashop-1-6-ssl-error-on-mobiles-tablets-using-chrome/31394603#31394603)

Is there any other way to get the attention of the author to his question?

Comment: You move on. What are you going to do, call the guy?

Comment: We cannot force people to return. If they don't respond, that's it, you move on.

Comment: *"Do you often meet with a similar situation"* Nope, because i don't go back to the question unless prompted via comments or votes.

Comment: Kill him. Quickly and efficiently. No mercy.

Comment: I'm just surprised that the authors do not care about checking their own questions.

Comment: It's a ghost question.  Who you gonna call?

Comment: They don't have to. It's bound to happen occasionally. Move on.

Comment: Well, you have to understand that this is entirely normal.  Very often the person *least* involved with the Q+A is the Q guy.  He just came here with a problem, if it doesn't get solved in 10 minutes or less then he already moved on.  The helpdesk didn't deliver.  Having an OP *really* involved is wonderful, it just doesn't happen very often.  No matter, the only thing that counts is the posed problem and how to best solve it.  Useful to the next thousands googlers that have the same problem and don't have 10 minutes.   It takes a while to get them to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user may be checking their question but not logged in anymore, though even if they do not there is nothing you can do as they will get notifications if you post an answer or a comment on the question. Also trying to contact the author by email is something you should not be doing as you should just rely on notifications to contact the authtor.

Comment: Sure, but it's quite annoying to not get any feedback ;).

Comment: @belford you'll eventually get feedback from the community :)